# nested mlflow runs in different scripts

Tags: mlflow

hi i have a python code comprised of main.py and pycaret_class.py.
main is looping on a dictionary values (5 keys) each key. each loop we call pycaret_class.py, run_pycaret method. in run_pycaret we set a mlflow experiment (all 5 runs in the loop have the same experiment name). so eventually we have 2 levels in our mlflow scheme:

<my_experiment_name>:

- run_name = first key
- run_name = second key
- run_name = third key
- run_name = fourth key
- run_name = fifth key

the user before running the main, has to input to file called params.py the following parameters: experiment_name, cover_name, cover_type. we have 4 cover names and 2 cover types.
cover_name: th, tl, tp, sd
cover_type: frequency, severity
we have 8 model: <cover_name>_<cover_type>. the user can decide if to run on just one model or all 8 models.

i want to add another level to my mlflow:

<my_experiment_name>:

- th_frequency
- tl_frequency
- tp_frequency
- sd_frequency
- th_severity
- tl_severity
- tp_severity
- sd_severity:

  - run_name = first key
  - run_name = second key
  - run_name = third key
  - run_name = fourth key
  - run_name = fifth key

each model will have 5 logs to mlflow with 5 different run name (all models will have the same run_names but with different results.

I tried in main.py before looping on the dictionary setting the experiment and define the parent_run:

**main.py**

```
pycaret_obj = PycaretObj()
mlflow.set_experiment(my_experiment_name)
parent_run = mlflow.start_run(run_name=f"{cover_name}_{cover_type}")
for k in my_dict.keys():
    pycaret_obj.run_pycaret(k, parent_run.info.run_id)
```

**pycaret_class.py**

```
def run_pycaret(d, parent_run_id):
   mlflow.set_experiment(my_experiment_name)
   with mlflow.start_run(run_name=d, nested=True, run_id=parent_run_id):
```

i also tried using mlflow.last_active_run and i keep getting the following exception:

> mlflow.exceptions.RestException: RESOURCE_NOT_EXIST: Run with id=.....
> not found